# Equivalent Open source Apache Ignite version to Gridgain Ignite version 8.5.8 and 8.7.13

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

Considering migrating from Gridgain Ignite version 8.5.8 or 8.7.13, what are the equivalent Apache Ignite versions to them.

Request to provide some insight with respect to equivalency of features and such that the applications will not be impacted due to this migration.

Please note: Gridgain additional features are currently not being used in my applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridGain 8.x.y is *loosely* equivalent to Ignite 2.x, so:

- 8.5.8 => 2.5
- 8.7.13 => 2.7

Keep in mind that release cycles and code bases are different, even though they share a lot of the same code.